# Install plugin ionic

Tags: leaflet, ionic4, npm-install

I want to use this plugin in my ionic application [search control leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-search) but when I launch the command

```
npm install --save leaflet-search
```

I get a 404 error

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/leaflet-search - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'leaflet-search@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

How can i fix this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you try again? it can be caused by the npm servers, It happens sometimes.

```
npm i leaflet-search
```